# Material ui table not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently updating my react site to 16.8 and have stumbled into an issue with a material ui table. In my app users pick some options, a rest call is then made when a user clicks a button, and the result of said call is added to the table.

Currently the table stays blank even when a result is returned. I've created an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rjv6t) of the behaviour using the material ui table example. (Note that the table data is in the format the web service returns it in, and I have also tried moving the arr.map function into the handleClick function and setting that as Arr, and then simply putting arr inside TableBody)

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
//imports done above here 
//example data used instead of performing rest call

var outRo = {
  id: 'Frozen yoghurt', 
  calories: 159, 
  fat: 6.0, 
  carbs: 24, 
  protein: 4.0,
};

export default function SimpleTable() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]); 

  function handleClick() {
    console.log('inside');
    //rest call gets data, stores into outRo 

    setArr(Array.from(outRo));
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick = {handleClick}> Add to Table </Button>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={'table'}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {arr.map(row => (
              <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell>
                  {row.id}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.protein}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.from(outRo)` is returning an empty array,

```js
var outRo = {
  id: "Frozen yoghurt",
  calories: 159,
  fat: 6.0,
  carbs: 24,
  protein: 4.0
};

console.log( Array.from(outRo) ); // []
```

to add the object to the array, do this :

```
function handleClick() {
  setArr([...arr, outRo]);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for adding one row! If multiple rows need to be added it seems to only add the last one, ignoring the previous. I have it set so handleClick goes to a function where the multiple responses are looped through, with each response going to an addToTable function, it seems to go inside this as many times as there are results correctly, just not actually show on the table.

Comment: @Uciebila yes it will add the same row each time, it's hardcoded, you should add those multiple responses so we can give more accurate answers,

Comment: this is as close as I can replicate it here! Hopefully this gives a better insight https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4fbgn

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT -** Requested to update answer to show how to include multiple items:

```
// imports removed for brevity
const row1 = {
  Name: "Frozen yoghurt",
  calories: 159,
  fat: 6.0,
  carbs: 24,
  protein: 4.0
};

const row2 = {
  Name: "foyo",
  calories: 222,
  fat: 4.0,
  carbs: 124,
  protein: 5.0
};

//results are captured and put into an array like such
var testAr = [];
testAr.push(row1, row2);

export default function SimpleTable() {
  const [resultRows, setResultRows] = useState([]);

  function handleClick() {
    setResultRows(testAr);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}> click</Button>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={"table"} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {resultRows.map(row => (
              <TableRow key={row.Name}>
                <TableCell>{row.Name} </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.protein}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is actually way easier than the first request, because you've already created the array from your objects.

So all you need to do, is use your **setResultRows** to push the newly created array, as above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, do you know how to make it work with multiple rows? (Like shown here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4fbgn) as at the moment it just ignores all other results apart from one

Comment: @Uciebila answer updated to include the multiple rows.